# How to use website search bar function in code

Tags: javascript, search, nlp

While a user can type in a search term in an onsite search bar directly, how can I do the same thing in code, especially when there is no known api? Say I want to know whether Macy's carry "baby shoes", how to do that in code? Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/

It lets you automate browser behavior, like entering text into a search bar and clicking search.

If the service you are interested in has no API, this is probably the way to go, but it might be considered rude (or against the site's terms of use), and I wouldn't be surprised if your script gets blocked by the search provider. If you expect to be running searches in any kind of appreciable volume, you should probably contact the search provider and talk to them about your use case. Maybe they can provide you with an API.

Since the question is tagged javascript, you might look into http://thechangelog.com/soda-selenium-node-js-adapter/ , which is a node adapter for selenium.

Comment: Thanks, Andbdrew! Does Selenium provide a way for me to grab the result page? It looks like the interface only tells me that it successfully performed a search, but doesn't provide a way for me to grab the search results.